# Difference between Execute Task and Submit Job?

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

When I compare my GPServer with sample service from ESRI. I notice difference.
In esri

Supported Operations:   **Execute Task**

my GPServer:

Supported Operations:    **Submit Job**

What is the difference between Task and Job??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execute Task for synchronous GP services and Submit Job for asynchronous GP services.

[From Esri Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01540000054v000000):

> Asynchronous and synchronous define how the client (the application
>   using the task) interacts with the server and gets the result from the
>   task. When a service is set to synchronous, the client waits for the
>   task to finish. Typically, a synchronous task executes quickly—five
>   seconds or less. An asynchronous task typically takes longer to
>   execute, and the client must periodically ask the server if the task
>   has finished and, if it has finished, get the result. A web
>   application using an asynchronous task must have logic implemented to
>   check the status of a task and handle the result once execution is
>   finished. ArcGIS Desktop clients handle both execution types natively.